# CKAN API Request doesn't work: `http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_list`

Tags: api, http, get, dataset, ckan

I've run into a strange problem that a simple API request doesn't work. I tried to call `http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_list` and `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/3/action/package_list`, and both resulted in the error: "No such file or directory".

When I run `http http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/3/action/package_list`, I get `"result": []`

If I browse CKAN through it's user interface, I can see the datasets.

Before running this command, I activated the virtual environment and started up CKAN server.

Do anyone know what might be the problem??

p.s. this same command worked before, but it doesn't work anymore today.. and I've tried to restart the virtual machine.. since I'm pretty new to development, it could also be that I missed some pre-conditions. Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Qing

Comment: Just to be clear, do you still get an error from the `http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_list` call? I get a response with the list of the datasets.

Comment: @McMutton 
I still get an error from running the command. My procedure of commands are:
1.  `. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate`  
2. `paster serve /etc/ckan/default/development.ini`  
3. start a new terminal and run `http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_list`  

Have I done anything wrong??

Comment: @Qing If you just open `http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_list` in a browser tab, do you get the "No such file or directory error"?

Comment: @user2895499 if I open it in a browser, it works fine. I get a list of data in JSON format.

Comment: @Qing I think the issue might be the way you're trying to access the API, then. If you have Requests installed ( `pip install requests` in a virtual environment if you don't), you should be able to get the data in JSON format by starting your Python interpreter and doing 1. `import requests` 2. `r = requests.get('http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_list')` 3. `print(r.json())`

Comment: @user2895499 Thanks a lot for your hint! I tried your method and it worked. Then I changed the call from `http` to `https` in CKAN command line and it solved the problem. The command become `http https://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_list`